# Broken if Evaluation in Templates

Tags: python, django

I have a conditional within a Django template that will create text a certain color if the expression evaluates true and another color if not. Note that I'm not actually going to have my styles in the HTML like in this example, but this makes it easier to give an example. Here's the code:

```
    <div class="span6 resultsBox">
        <h2>Items:  
            {% if user.items >= user.itemsQuota %}
            <span id="items" style="color:green">{{ user.items}} </span>
            {% else %}
            <span id="items" style="color:white">{{ user.items }} </span>
            {% endif %} 
            / {{user.itemsQuota }}.
        </h2><br />
    </div>
```

No matter what I do, the resulting `span` text is green! Normally I'd think there's something wrong with my models and how they are calculating equality, but even when the out put is something like `100/1000`, where clearly `{{ user.items }}` is less than `{{ user.itemsQuota }}`, the green font occurs! What am I missing here with my conditionals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be `user.items` is a string and `user.itemsQuota` is a number. In Python (before 3.x), `'100' > 1000` is True.

Quick demo:

```
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure()

t = Template('{% if a > b %} a > b {% else %} a <= b {% endif %}')
print t.render(Context({ 'a' : '100', 'b' : 1000 }))
print t.render(Context({ 'a' : 100  , 'b' : 1000 }))
```

prints:

```
a > b 
a <= b
```

If you want a template-only solution, this works:

```
t = Template('{% if a|add:"0" > b|add:"0" %} a > b {% else %} a <= b {% endif %}')
```

(because `add` coerces the values to integers)

Comment: The `add` trick worked, but none of them were strings. `itemsQuota` was an integer variable, and items was a `PositiveIntegerField`. I thought it would automatically convert to an integer in the template language, but I guess I need to perform this "cast."